# Why I am unable to access the data from my API which is in a localhost?

Tags: python, reactjs, json, backend, flask-restful

I am trying to build a movie recommendation system. I need to connect the python backend to the ReactJS frontend using Flask framework. My python code is showing correct outputs and the localhost is also showing the JSON file. But when I try to integrate to the front-end to list the movie names as a dropdown menu, my menu is empty.

My flask code is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selected_movie = request.form['movie-select']
        return {selected_movie}
    else:
        titles = [movie["original_title"] for movie in movies_final]
        return jsonify(titles)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I created a Dropdown.js file to create a dropdown menu.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function MovieDropDown() {
  const [movies, setMovies] = useState([]);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5000/titles', {mode : 'no-cors'})  // replace with your Flask API endpoint URL
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        const moviesList = Object.entries(data).map(([id, title]) => ({ id, title }));
        console.log(moviesList);
        setMovies(moviesList);
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }, []);

  const filteredMovies = movies.filter(movie =>
    movie.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="movie-search">Search for a movie:</label>
      <input
        id="movie-search"
        type="text"
        value={searchTerm}
        onChange={event => setSearchTerm(event.target.value)}
      />
      {filteredMovies.length > 0 ? (
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="movie-select">Select a movie:</label>
          <select id="movie-select">
            {filteredMovies.map(movie => (
              <option key={movie.id} value={movie.title}>{movie.title}</option>
            ))}
          </select>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>No movies found.</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default MovieDropDown;
```

Why I am getting an empty dropdown menu?

Comment: Are you sure it's running on localhost:5000? Do you see an incoming request in Flask when you visit the HTML page? How exactly is the JS being pulled in and called?

Comment: can you curl/hit that endpoint (http://127.0.0.1:5000/titles) directly?

Comment: The route is for `/`, not for `/titles`